# OOP Javascript 'this' keyword in a nested private method

Tags: javascript, oop, this

Here is some example code:

```
ExampleClass = function()
{
    this.initiate();
};

ExampleClass.prototype.initiate = function()
{
    var connect = function()
    {
        this.sendNOP();
    };

    connect();
};

ExampleClass.prototype.sendNOP = function()
{
    console.info('Sending NOP...');
    var callback = function()
    {
        console.info('Server responded to NOP. ZzzZzzzZzz...');
    };
    setTimeout(callback, 1500);
};
```

I am very curious why I can't call `this.sendNOP()` in `ExampleClass.initiate` so that `ExampleClass.initiate._connect()` will pass the instanceof `ExampleClass` as `this` to `ExampleClass.sendNOP()`, it seems to pass `window` as `this`. Why?

**EDIT:**

The problem is when we call `ExampleClass.initiate._connect()` we only use `connect()` which does not specify any context. Calling `ExampleClass.initiate._connect()` with `.apply(this)` works! `.apply(this)` sets the context to `ExampleClass`.

```
ExampleClass.prototype.appliedInitiate = function()
{
    var connect = function()
    {
        this.sendNOP();
    };

    connect.apply(this);
};
```

**Final code**

```
ExampleClass = function()
{  
    this.appliedInitiate();
};

ExampleClass.prototype.sendNOP = function()
{
    console.info('Sending NOP...');
    var callback = function()
    {
        console.info('Server responded to NOP. ZzzZzzzZzz...');
    };
    setTimeout(callback, 1500);
};

ExampleClass.prototype.initiate = function()
{
    var connect = function()
    {
        this.sendNOP();
    };

    connect(); // Won't work. connect() is not called from any context (ie. obj.connect() )
};

ExampleClass.prototype.appliedInitiate = function()
{
    var connect = function()
    {
        this.sendNOP();
    };

    connect.apply(this); // Will work, we are calling connect with apply, which sets the context to ExampleClass
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't calling `this.sendNOP` in `ExampleClass.initiate`. You are calling it in `connect`. That the call to `connect` is inside the `initiate` function is irrelevant.

You haven't called `connect` with any context, so the context is the default object (`window`).

Comment: +1 and as addition one of my favorite SO javascript questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: Calling connect with `.apply()` doesn't seem to change a thing. How am I supposed to elegantly fight this problem?

Comment: It should do. How are you using it?

Comment: How are you calling `ExampleClass`?

Comment: @Quentin I am doing it through the constructor; `exc = new ExampleClass()`

Comment: @Quentin paste the codes in a js console (chrome, ff, w/e) and try it out

Comment: You don't have the same problem. `this` is no longer `window`. The new problem is that `sendNOP` is a method of **ExampleClass** and not the prototype. You need `ExampleClass.prototype.sendNOP = ...`

Comment: @Quentin ah yes I discovered that a little after I wrote the last messages and started correcting the code. The solution is in the initial post now, with explanations.